# Flutter: How to make a text editor?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, editor, native

[image]

Is there a library that provides this functionality?

(It will be develop as a Flutter. Android & iOS)

I couldn't find out about this function.
I think... Add more than "<Button>" And It creates the OnClick Event function.
Is it right?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two packages that might fit your needs: https://pub.dev/packages/text_editor, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill